# Load Blade assets with https in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, https, laravel-blade

I am loading my css using this format:
    `<link href="{{ asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
and it loads fine for all http requests

But when I load my login page with SSL (https), I get a `...page... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http...`

Can someone please tell me how do I make blade load assets over https instead of http?

Should I be trying to load the assets securely? Or is it not Blade's job?

Comment: I know it's been several years, but I would suggest unmarking my answer as the accepted answer and picking [Scofield's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel/45731506#45731506) as the correct one. His is far more useful and flexible than my own, and this is a pretty high quality question that people are finding organically on their own.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

I had a problem with `asset` function when it's loaded resources through HTTP protocol when the website was using HTTPS, which is caused the "Mixed content" problem.

To fix that you need to add `\URL::forceScheme('https')` into your `AppServiceProvider` file.

So mine looks like this (Laravel 5.4):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is helpful when you need https only on server (`config('app.env') === 'production'`) and not locally, so don't need to force `asset` function to use https.

Comment: this is a better answer, since I want to only use https on production server

Comment: Agreed. While my answer might have addressed the question directly, this approach would likely be better in cases where you have multiple environments that may or may not be serving over HTTPS.

Comment: Only on Production make better sense and fit my case.

Comment: I used this same pattern, but instead of just checking 'app.env', I looked at 'app.url'. If it starts with 'https', then I force the scheme.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I believe. I had another problem with login form submission. Both fixed when I forced the https in the service provider class.

Comment: can use this as well
   `if(!app()->isLocal())
    {
                \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }`

Comment: This is no longer the right way of doing this. You should be using the TrustProxies middleware...

Answer (score 92):

I believe [secure_asset](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset) is what you're looking for.

```
<link href="{{ secure_asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**5/15/2018 Edit:** While my answer addresses the question directly, it's a bit dated given what Laravel can do nowadays; there may be cases where you want to force HTTPS on certain environments but not on others.

[See Scofield's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel/45731506#45731506) for a more flexible solution to cover for these kinds of cases.

**08/11/2020 Edit:** Seriously guys, [Scofield's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel/45731506#45731506) is better than mine and will provide more flexibility for differing environments. Give him your updoots.

Comment: This will not work if you are working with virtual host on your local machine, insted of changing from asset to secure_asset you should update your AppServiceProvider->boot function 
```
$url->forceScheme('https');
```
you can also put this in if condition like this
```
if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
            $url->forceScheme('https');
        }
```
and remember to run command "php artisan config:clear".

Comment: @HiteshKumar Where did you hear that it "will not work"? This will work just fine on a virtual host on your local machine, just as long as you know how to generate and trust your own certificate. You can also review my edit from over two years ago pointing out that this answer is not as well-rounded as Scofield's answer below. Your suggestion to use `artisan config:clear` is also superfluous and does nothing in this scenario, since no configurations are changed in either my or Scofield's approaches.

Comment: because I already tried, and I am suggesting "artisan config:clear" because of if condition of local and production environment this will clear add->config and load .env variables.
This can work in older version of laravel but in letest it changed.

Comment: This is not a valid solution since we need to change everywhere in the files wherever we've used.

Comment: @TarangP Yeah. We know. Look at all of the edits on this question. I had OP change the answer.

Answer (score 59):

There is a environment variable "ASSET_URL" where you put your app url with the http or https

```
ASSET_URL=https://your.app.url #for production
```

or

```
ASSET_URL=http://your.app.url #for local development
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why write 10-20 lines of code when its already there.

Comment: This is the best answer! It works for me

Comment: It works like a charm in v8.54. This solution is much better since all you have to do is override a default variable in your `.env` or create one if it's not there.

Comment: It works perfectly and is much simpler

Answer (score 38):

I use @Scofield answer by use `\URL::forceScheme('https');` This solution also worked to show https for all routes **but this not worked for me for $request->url() it show http instead of https**

so I used `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);` instead of `\URL::forceScheme('https');`

**I'm using Laravel 5.4** and update **.env file and appserviceproviders**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Log;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        If (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

in my env file I've changed

```
APP_ENV=local to APP_ENV=development
```

APP_ENV=local for localhost
APP_ENV=development/production for on working server

after changing env run this artisan command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope It helps :-)

Comment: @NavaBogatee happy to hear this. :-)

Comment: config:clear is unnecessary if instead using env(), use config() or $this->app->environment()

Answer (score 15):

An another approach would be to pass `true` as the second parameter.

```
/**
 * Generate an asset path for the application.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

As you see below `secure_asset` simply calls `asset` with the second parameter `true`.

```
/**
 * Generate an asset path for the application.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @return string
 */
function secure_asset($path)
{
    return asset($path, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative suggestion :)

Answer (score 11):

Figuring out if the current `Request` is secure or not should not be your decision. Underlying `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` has `isSecure` method that Laravel uses internally.

```
public function isSecure()
{
    if ($this->isFromTrustedProxy() && $proto = $this->getTrustedValues(self::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO)) {
        return \in_array(strtolower($proto[0]), array('https', 'on', 'ssl', '1'), true);
    }

    $https = $this->server->get('HTTPS');

    return !empty($https) && 'off' !== strtolower($https);
}
```

So if your server is not passing the `HTTPS` header with `On`, it should be passing `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` and must be allowed by your `TrustProxies` middleware.

If you are behind reverse-proxy you should find out your proxy pass IP - you can do this easily by getting the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable and setting the IP to your `TrustProxies` middleware:

```
/**
 * The trusted proxies for this application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $proxies = [
    '123.123.123.123',
];
```

Laravel (Symfony) will then automatically detect if the `Request` is secure or not and choose the protocol accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is cloudflare on my local machines is working fine but online server not solution is

```
 public function boot()
    {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
             \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is my configuration to make HTTPS working with assets. To enable this in production add REDIRECT_HTTPS=true in the .env file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS'))
        {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Improving even more the answer of colleague [Paulo Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68287406/10300376) above, which should have been accepted as an answer, for being extremely practical, in the .env file just insert this config if your `APP_URL` already contains `https://`:

```
ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

Answer (score 1):

in .env file please change the value local to production

```
APP_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `"{{ asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') }}"` use `"{{ secure_asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting this in my blade file:

```
@if(parse_url(url('/'), PHP_URL_SCHEME) == 'HTTPS')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('assets/css/slider.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ secure_asset('assets/css/dropdown.css') }}">
@else
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/slider.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/dropdown.css') }}">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading Laravel version from 5.4 to 5.5, I had the same issue.

Just add `\URL::forceScheme('https');` in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php. It worked.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to combine [@Jan Richter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52049183/7619826) with [@Ozan Kurt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378333/7619826).

Since @Richter's answer let you use Symfony's built-in `isSecure()` function, which is already integrated with Laravel's request, you can easily call it as `$request->isSecure()`, then use its return value to serve the assets via @Kurt's approach.

A sample code would be like this:

```php
    protected function index(Request $req) {
        return view('index', [
            'isSecure' => $req->isSecure();
        ]);
    }
```

```php
...
<link href="{{ asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css', $isSecure) }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
...
```

OR just use the Request directly from the blade:

```php
@php ($isSecure = Request::isSecure())
<link href="{{ asset('assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css', $isSecure) }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

## EDITS

---

- EDIT[0]: Fixed Ozan Kurt's answer link
- EDIT[1]: Fixed both answer links (and edit's format)