# laravel asset() method doesn't return https

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `asset()` public method to generate correct url in laravel.

in docs it says:

[image]

So in theory it should detect correct scheme itself.

But in code I see: https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/UrlGenerator.php#L210

```
public function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
```

default for secure is null. So this method is no good for both http/https.

what am I missing here?

I'm using reverse proxy, could it because of that?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to check it without proxy? Like `curl http://localhost/page_that_contains_the_asset`.

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't get the question.

Comment: I wouldn't change anything in the code like people are suggesting if you can force HTTPS usage via the .htaccess file.

Comment: @ThomasYates I'm using ssl reverse proxy in front, but laravel doesn't return correct url via asset(). With this question I'm trying to understand why. It seems reverse proxy is messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from GitHub the `asset` method is calling `getScheme` to determine what the scheme should be.

https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/UrlGenerator.php#L303

```
public function formatScheme($secure = null)
{
    if (! is_null($secure)) {
        return $secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    }
    if (is_null($this->cachedScheme)) {
        $this->cachedScheme = $this->forceScheme ?: $this->request->getScheme().'://';
    }
    return $this->cachedScheme;
}
```

So if you don't provide the `asset` 2nd parameter `$secure` then it uses the request scheme. Otherwise you can provide `$secure` to force the desired scheme regardless of what is the scheme in the request.

If you look at the code you'll see that if `$secure` is null and no cache is set than the cache is set to the request scheme (i.e. `$this->request->getScheme()`) and therefore returned.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So my problem is `this->request->getScheme()` doesn't realize I'm using https. Because of reverse proxy maybe.

Comment: Could be reverse proxy indeed but I think Apache can be configured to reverse on https as well so you may need to do some tuning there. Try to dump the request data to see what's the last node and what you get there if http or https.

Comment: I'm using nginx, but that's besides the point. I've `< client browser > < ssl nginx > < 80 nginx > < laravel >`

Comment: I don't want to force https between nginxes, because its on same server there is no need. But I want laravel to see schema correctly

Comment: Uhm... I'm afraid for the nginx thing there's room for a separate question. Can only point you to the docs in the comments: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/

Comment: well, I've setup everything correctly in nginx. so that doc file is not helping. My problem is combination of reverse proxy and laravel that doesn't work right.

Comment: I don't think Laravel or generically speaking your PHP application is the problem. I think it's more a matter of passing the right information along between the 2 Nginx servers. Doesn't sound like a PHP question to me, try on serverfault.com maybe?

Comment: oh that dead place :) nobody answers anything on serverfault. anyways, I found the problem `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` in nginx conf

Answer (score 4):

Please stop writing code for doing things that already exist.
There is a ASSET_URL env variable. Use it.

```
ASSET_URL=https://your.app.url #in env for production

ASSET_URL=http://your.app.url #in env for local development
```

( https://stackoverflow.com/a/68287406/7481663 )

Answer (score 3):

isn't it `secure_asset` you're looking for?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-secure-asset

Comment: no, that would force https only. I want solution that is equivalent to `//`

Comment: @salivan Not the best solution, but if what you want is `//`, why not replace the "http" in the `asset()` url for "" since it always outputs urls starting with `http://`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that happens because the reverse proxy will do SSL termination, which means that the browser requests https, but the request that goes from the proxy to the app is http. This has many benefits (improved performance) but it does have this side-effect.

I think the solution would go as an environment variable that tells you to force https (when using the web on staging or production) or to leave as http when e.g. developing locally.

I think is the most effective. I say this because your app will never know when to use https or not.

Answer (score 1):

On the very same file, you have a definition of the getScheme() method, which uses the $secure parameter.

If the $secure parameter is the default `null` value, the scheme is either guessed from the current scheme, or retrieved from the previous saved scheme (If it hasn't been forced with forceSchema()).

You could tell the $secure parameter works that way :

- `true` will force https
- `false` will force http
- `null` will use the best scheme, guessed from the current scheme

Here's the code from the getScheme() method :

```
protected function getScheme($secure)
{
    if (is_null($secure)) {
        if (is_null($this->cachedSchema)) {
            $this->cachedSchema = $this->forceSchema ?: $this->request->getScheme().'://';
        }
        return $this->cachedSchema;
    }
    return $secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: I didn't saw you already have answered yet, while redacting my answer.

Comment: Yeah they were too close I guess ;-)

Comment: I see, so my problem is `this->request->getScheme()` cannot guess schema correctly, because of reverse proxy maybe?

Comment: Maybe. But could you guess your current scheme and pass it through the method as the second parameter ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault shouldn't `asset()` be doing that automatically? I'm trying to understand why it fails.

Comment: Yes, it should, but I'm not proficient enough with proxies to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone falls into this same issue like I did in order to allow the `asset` function to get the proper schema you would have to enable `TrustedProxies`.
In laravel there is a middleware that does that for you in `\App\Http\Middleware\TrustedProxies` but you must included it in your default middleware before it can take effect.

Laravel uses the `fideloper/TrustedProxy` package which sets the `trustedProxies` array in the `Request` object which is checked in order to approve the `X-Forwarded-Proto` provided in the header.

You can check the following link to get more details

[Explains in Laravel Trusted Proxy in details](https://fideloper.com/laravel-4-trusted-proxies)

[For Setting it up](https://packagist.org/packages/fideloper/proxy)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some maintenance in some legacy systems built in Laravel 4.2 and stumbled in this situation.

After giving a look at how the Generators are instantiated and used, I solved the problem setting the `UrlGenerator` `forcedSchema` property after the environment detection at the `start.php` file of the application.

```
// The if condition depends on what identifies your https host
if( str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'secure_app_host_fragment')){
    $app['url']->forceSchema('https');
}
```

Code:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7d9e7068c49f945385673014d4cba4de28accd5e/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L204