# Blocked:Mixed-Content error while loading Laravel CSS and JS in HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, https

I am using Laravel version 5.5.39 and hosted my instance in AWS with ELB along with SSL from Amazon certificate Manager. While loading the website it shows secure and in few seconds it is back with non secure as my css and js is getting "blocked:mixed-content" error in Developer tools.  My certificate is valid, but the https is not working properly, any help would be greatly appreciated?

OS-Amazon Linux, Apache - Apache/2.4.27

Comment: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: This may be an `htaccess` syntax problem with a 301 redirect.  Show us your `.htaccess` -- And your Laravel `config`

Answer (score 0):

@Zak, please find the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Zak, thanks for editing the .htaccess, this is what exactly I have, can you please provide your suggestions for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solutions for the same problems from

1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mixed-content-issue-content-must-be-served-as-https
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-mixed-content-error-when-viewing-website-over-https?page=1
3. [Load Blade assets with https in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel)

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions, issue has been fixed by the solutions provided in this link "https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mixed-content-issue-content-must-be-served-as-https"

Answer (score 0):

The mixed content error is due to the usage of non-ssl urls with http in your code. For example: if you are using google fonts like

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:300" rel="stylesheet">
```

that is http instead of https within your site it will cause the issue. 
Please check if all the url you are using within the site has https instead of http. Hope this helps.