# CSS and JS not working after deployed in heroku

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, heroku

i worked with laravel 5.7, in local it run good, but after i deployed the app to production server (heroku) the CSS and JS seems not working. what should i do?

this the url "https://arrahnu-demo.herokuapp.com/

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Arrahnu Gadai Indonesia</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta content="" name="description">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="{{asset('/img/favicon.png')}}" rel="icon">
  <link href="{{asset('/img/apple-touch-icon.png')}}" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:300,400,500,700,800|Montserrat:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->

  <link href="{{asset('/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/animate/animate.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesh">
  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="{{asset('/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
```

Comment: Try to replace relative URLs with absolute one based on your runtime environment. So, replace the call to {{asset('/css/style.css')}}, which is a relative URL processed by the asset() helper, with a absolute URL for every file needed. If in production, do https://<yourDomain.Name>/css/style.css And if local, do https://localhost:<PORT>/css/style.css Every framework/language/environment has a way to detect if you are local (in dev machine) or remote (in a production or test machine). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ranieribt, i was solve the problem with this way, but really dont understand, what actually happend to my code, could you explain that.

Answer (score 3):

Your `<link>`s are fetching http instead of https.
And as your website on Heroku is served through https, the browser is blocking the mixed content.

Comment: This was indeed the cause of the problem a solution can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel/45731506#45731506