# Laravel basic auth redirects to HTTPS route after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I added laravel’s built-in authentication to an existing project. This is a local project without certificates.

After login I was redirected to the dashboard page but chrome showed an “ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR” message. I looked into it for a couple of hours and I found that the dashboard's page was opening as HTTPS, when I changed the url to HTTP It showed the dashboard page. For some reason the auth’s routes are being redirected to the site as HTTPS.

I'm new to laravel and I don't understand what’s happening.

Comment: Are you sure it is Laravel causing this and not maybe Chrome/a chrome extension? Never had this happen

Comment: I have tried in Firefox and Microsoft Edge and had the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reverse engineering and found that in my AppServiceProvider were the configurations that redirected my routes to HTTPS.

[Load Blade assets with https in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel)