# Is there a way to make my laravel project to use https from form just as the route

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I have been given a task to maintain an old project that is in Laravel. So I have hosted it in ec2 and placed a load balancer to it and then placed SSL on it.

Now my routes work well for example I have https://example.com. But when I go to the login form I see that the links within the webpage are:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com/category/design">
```

Now I saw the Laravel version is 6.0. I have checked online on how to redirect http to https. The route is okay but the links within the webpage are not https as the route shows.

I am asking for some help in how to also make my links within the webpage also be https

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check in your .env file and make sure the APP_URL has https://?

Comment: @MihirBhende its what i did in the first place. I mean the site actually has https on it. but the forms do not have

Comment: Force all http routes to https using .htaccess.

Comment: @RakibulIslam when i change from the .htaccess file i get an error of too many redirects

Comment: Found the solution from her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel