# I need to redirect all http url to https in laravel 8 (becz error Mixed content issue)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, web

I need to redirect all internal URL (inside the HTML page generated by laravel) it may be generated by laravel coding as well as predefined by vendor function all HTTP URL should be redirected from HTTP to HTTPS

example: src="http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php"

redirect to src="https://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php"

Thank you

Comment: i done all sujections but again vew my page sorce still in http  dade i cpoy pested here 
 
    <script language="Javascript">var _skz_pid = "9PO5645V6";</script>
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loader" id="sk-loader"></div>

Comment: this link has an external script so it's better to download and load from the asset. did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

set this line in `AppServiceProvider` file boot function

if you want HTTPS only in production environment you can try this also

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    if(config('app.env') === 'production') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

reference : [Load Blade assets with https in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your `APP_URL` in **.env** to `https://yourdomain.com`.
2. Add `REDIRECT_HTTPS=true` to your **.env** then open `AppServiceProvider.php` and in the `boot()` function, add this:

   ```
   if (env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
       $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', 'on');
   }
   ```