# How is Laravel detecting http vs https?

Tags: laravel

I have a webapp accessed via https://domain.ext

Main APP_URL in the .env is https://domain.ext

The app is behind a proxy

The problem is that generated asset url actually are prefixed with http:// instead of https://

Why ?

> I triple-checked: i cleared my cache

Also i noticed that mix() urls are relative. And work
But asset() generated url are using http instead of https

Please, reply to the question: how is laravel detecting https vs http?

When I understand when/how I can try to understand if my customer has a bad-configured proxy or whatelse.

Comment: `APP_URL` has nothing to do with the browser app.

Comment: Have you cleared the config (i.e. `php artisan config:clear`) after changing env values?

Comment: Yes yes. I cleared all. Added to OP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378122/load-blade-assets-with-https-in-laravel
There are multiple ways to solve this problem, depending on what you prefer, it is hard to tell where the configuration problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's a well-constructed proxy that sends the right `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers, you'll need to configure Laravel to [trust the proxy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) in `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies`.